# Template function compilng error

Tags: c++

I have .inl and .cpp files, .inl file contains template function and i had declared global variable in that like below,

**int global_value =0;**
and linking to .cpp file by using extern keyword after compiling  that  program i got below error

mutiple declaration error
first defined here error

could any one suggest me why i am getting this error?

Comment: can you post more of the actual code?  I.e. trim down the .inl and .cpp file to the minimal necessary to cause the error, and post that here.

Comment: .inl is just for things with inline linkage in your use case, which global_value is not.

Comment: I think you should use some `#define`s (macroes).

Answer (score 2):

In short - on the cpp file, have:

`int global_value = 0;`

and on the inl file, have:

`extern int global_value;`

The global variable should be declared in one and only one translation unit (cpp file). All other translation units should use `extern`, either directly or via some header file. In your case, every translation that includes the .inl file effectively declares the global, hence the error. So, have it declared in the cpp, and place the `extern` in the inl (assuming you include the inl file in other cpp files).

Comment: Thanks for your reply i will try that too.. More over Am pretty new in c++ i need further clarification, .inl contains class  template function  it is also c++ function right ? so why they defined in .inl format? it is under /CLASSLIB/array.inl they  same way  it having array.h file also, so now what am want to do means  need to declare one  variable globally like above i mentioned , and In every template function first line  i have to call AASSERT(global_value!=0);  the global variable make true in cpp file can you please assist me with sample program

Comment: @Srini, templates compilation can be a bit tricky - you should probably read more about it. In short, inl files usually contain _definitions_ (i.e. implementations), as opposed to h files that contain _declarations_. They could have been cpp files, but including cpp files is considered a bad practice. So inl files are just a way to `include` definitions of template functions. Now that I think of it, it might be better to have the `extern int global_value` in the h file. Both will work, though.

Comment: thanks could you provide sample program it will be more helpful

Comment: @Srini, just use the code in my answer - place the first part in one cpp file (say array.cpp) and the second in either array.h or array.inl (if in array.h, before the `#include "array.inl"`. If in array.inl, before the functions.

Comment: thanks earn and one more question that .cpp file contains m_states.setAt(identifer+1,pState); setAt--->template function(.inl). while putting gdb  before that setAt function   global_value should be true then only AASSERT function will call how can i put global value that in cpp file?

Comment: after changing what ever you said yesterday now got this error ypt -lsigtran -lsctp -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread -lm -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lframework
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [obj_lnx26_d/radius] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/vob/cnsar/thin/destiny/servers/radius/src'
make: *** [servers] Error 2

Comment: @Srini, that's an unrelated error. Only reason you get it now is because you've when passed the previous error. I'm not familiar with the details you provide, you'd better ask about this on a new question.

Comment: while globally compiling i got follwing error .. g++-3.4.1 -I../../include -I../../local/include-lnx26 -I../../latest/include -DDEBUG -fno-implicit-templates -fcheck-new -c -Wall -g -m32 -Wa,--32 -MD -o obj_lnx26_d/licensemanager.o licensemanager.cpp
In file included from ../../local/include-lnx26/aarray.h:117,
from licensemanager.h:16,
from licensemanager.cpp:10:
../../local/include-lnx26/aarray.inl:24:29: remoteudpserver.h: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [obj_lnx26_d/licensemanager.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [local] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: @Srini, you should ask this in a new StackOverflow question. This question was about the linker error you got from the declaration of a global variable, which I believe I have fully answered. Your new question involves some file or directory not being found. Please ask about it in a new question, and if my answer solved your previous issue, accept it so this question is considered answered.